# Как вернуть объект через функцию при помощи оператора распространения?

Tags: javascript, функции

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вернуть объект его копией, при этом изменив одно из значений ключа в изначальном объекте? Слышал про `Object.assign({})`, но он изменяет изначальный объект, а я бы хотел получить копию c измененным значением + оригинальный объект.

```
let color_lawn = {
    title: 'lawn',
    color: '#00FF00',
    rating: 0
}

const getColorRating = (color, rating) => ({
    ...color.rating
})

console.log(getColorRating(color_lawn, 5);
```

Comment: иногда меня удивляют как люди пишут сами не понимают что..... понимаю когда задают вопросы о том что не знают........но когда при этом код показывают, который от реальности оторван......ну это нечто.....`getColorRating(console.log(color_lawn, 5))` это в музей надо

Comment: Друг, это пример из книги по JS. Я думаю, что с такой претензией лучше обратиться к автору книги.

Comment: ой да лаааадно. ну-ка скрин кинь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет тега "Музей"? Я бы вопрос про ЭВМ туда же отправил ))

Comment: Подозреваю, что там было написано `(console.log(getColorRating(color_lawn, 5))` в лучшем случае )

Comment: Да, я ошибся. Не судите строго. Учусь только)

Comment: @SwaD, есть цитатный чат.

Comment: @Qwertiy Что за цитатный чат? Чего еще я не открыл для себя здесь? )

Comment: @SwaD, как раз сегодня разморозил: [вот он](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50845/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let color_lawn = {
  title: 'lawn',
  color: '#00FF00',
  rating: 0
}

const getColorRating = (color, rating) => ({
  ...color_lawn,
  color,
  rating,
})

console.log(getColorRating('#555555', 1))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Gleym, я ещё немного обновил - теперь явного `return` тоже нет.

Comment: Да, так раз хотел узнать, можно ли без `return` написать. Спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 1):

Для создания копии объекта можно воспользоваться **spread** оператором, но он копирует только 1 уровень. Если в объекте есть другие объекты, то они будут переданы по ссылке

```js
let color_lawn = {
  title: 'lawn',
  color: '#00FF00',
  rating: 0
}

const getColorRating = (color, rating) => {
  const newColor = { ...color_lawn }
  newColor.color = color;
  newColor.rating = rating;
  return newColor;
}

const color_q = getColorRating('#555555', 1);
console.log(color_q === color_lawn)
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!

Comment: Проще можно....

Comment: @Qwertiy Век живи, век учись ) Надо почитать подробнее будет